# Flash CS5 Draggable Movie Thoughts?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, user-interface

I'd like to create a draggable timeline similar to:
http://www.skar.com/timeline.html

I need some ideas on how to best accomplish it.

Would it be best to create one large Movie Clip that acts as a container to all my individual images. Then code an onDrag handler that moves that container's X value based on the mouse's X value.

Thanks,
Tegan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started writing how to do this, but then realized that there must be a tutorial on this just searched for flash parallax, lo and behold the [first thing](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/parallax-gallery/) did it :)

I should point out that your sample is not doing it properly, as the middle-ground is tweening one direction when the foreground is going another direction. It just doesn't seem right.